# how to add a mouse listener to a JTable's cell holding a Boolean value rendered as checkbox

Tags: java, swing, jtable, mouselistener, jcheckbox

I have a JTable with a custom model implemented extending AbstractTableModel.

```
public abstract class AbstractTable extends AbstractTableModel{

     public Class<? extends Object> getColumnClass(int c) {}
}
```

Because I've implemented the getColumnClass method, Boolean values are rendered in the table like checkboxes.
I would like to intercept checkbox's change of status but unfortunately I can't add directly a mouse listener, because I don't have a reference to the checkbox itself, which it isn't created by me.

How can I set a mouse listener to intercept the checkbox status change event?

EDIT:

@jzd answer is correct. I can catch the change in setValue method. But I would like to know how to implement a mouse listener based approach.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Particularly, I would like to avoid putting the logic inside `setValue()`.

In this [example](https://sites.google.com/site/drjohnbmatthews/table) of selectable values, the `setValue()` method is not overridden, *except to update the internal data structure and fire the appropriate event*. `ValueEditor` extends `AbstractCellEditor` and implements `ItemListener`, while `ValueRenderer` extends `JCheckBox`. In this way the editor can listen to the renderer's `JCheckBox` inside the editor's `itemStateChanged()`.

Addendum: Adding a `CellEditorListener` is another approach, shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11113648/230513) for `JTree`. Note that `JTable` itself is a `CellEditorListener`.

Comment: +1... This has to be the 10th trashgod post that has helped me immensely with Swing this week!

Comment: @The111: Glad to help; I've updated the answer to clarify the distinction between _editing_ and _updating_.

Comment: In the first example, what is reason for creating two instances of ValueRenderer?

Comment: One is used as a cell renderer; the other serves the cell editor.

Answer (score 6):

I can't resist with @jzd advice really no, I think that not, not ensure me going throught `TableMode#setValue`,

but basically there are two options

1) TableModelListener

2) AFAIK only TableCellEditor#isCellEditable can do that in connections with JCheckBox or JRadioButton in JTable

```
public boolean isCellEditable(EventObject getEvent) {
    MouseEvent me = (MouseEvent) getEvent;
    JTable table = (JTable) (me.getSource());
    Point point = me.getPoint();
    int column = table.columnAtPoint(point);
    int row = table.rowAtPoint(point);
    Rectangle rec = table.getCellRect(row, column, true); 
    //... 
 }
```

Answer (score 3):

Seems like adding a mouse listener is an extra step.  I would suggest intercepting the change in the `setValue()` method of the model.

If you can't change the `setValue()` method then the next best thing is a `CustomEditor` that will block changes because this is not a good way to catch and hide the mouse click even from the default boolean editor.

Comment: Yes I could. Anyway I would like to know if it is also possible and how do that, with a mouse listener. I do that way since now. My table model class is a bit complicated. I would like to use mouse listener to keep away the action that I want to perform on status changed, from the table model itself. Particularly I would like to avoid putting the logic inside setValue. thanks anyway

Comment: +1 A custom editor and renderer is the right way to go. I've described an example [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6270351/how-to-add-a-mouse-listener-to-a-jtables-cell-holding-a-boolean-value-rendered-a/6273093#6273093).

Answer (score 0):

I was having exactly the same problem,  and I also know that you asked specifically for a mouse listener to the checkbox editor, but a workarround might be adding a  `TableModelListener` as described [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#modelchange) under the section "Listening for Data Changes", and try to simulate the behavior when you detect the change, but if you want to know when the mouse is over the checkbox or things like that < specific actions of the mouse >, I'm affraid that you'll have to make yout own implementation of a cell Editor, which implements those behaviors... At least thats what I would do...

Grettings!...