# adding actionlistener to jcheckbox in java

Tags: java, swing, jtable, actionlistener, jcheckbox

I use the following code to generate a table with three columns and three rows, the first column contains checkboxes, and the second column just contains the word : row i, where i corresponds to the row number.

```
private void loadTable {
       int rowCount  = 3;
     Boolean [] boolArray  = new Boolean[3];

     for(int y=0;y<3;y++)
         boolArray[y]=false;

     int columnCount = 2;
     Object data[] = new Object [rowCount];
      for(int y=1;y<=3;y++)
         data[y-1]="row "+y;

     mainModel = new DefaultTableModel();
     mainModel.addColumn("", boolArray);
     mainModel.addColumn("", data);
       jScrollPane1.getViewport().add(tableOne, null);
     aTableClass.setModel(mainModel);

}     




class ATableClass extends JTable {
              public Class getColumnClass(int column) {
                try {
                  if (column == 0) {
                    return Class.forName("java.lang.Boolean");
                  }
                  return Class.forName("java.lang.Object");
                }
                catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
                  ex.printStackTrace();
                  return null;
                }
              }
            }
```

How can I add actionlisteners to the generated checkboxes inside this table ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to define your custom cell table renderers and editors, and add the action listener to the rendered components .
Have a look at this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6270351/how-to-add-a-mouse-listener-to-a-jtables-cell-holding-a-boolean-value-rendered-a). 
This [example](https://sites.google.com/site/drjohnbmatthews/table) has been very helpful to me.

In a few word you have to:

1. implement somewhere `TableCellRenderer` interface (define how your column will be rendered)
2. implement somewhere `TableCellEditor` interface (define how your column will be edited)
3. adding to your `JTable` the desired renderer and editor ([setDefaultRenderer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html#setDefaultRenderer%28java.lang.Class,%20javax.swing.table.TableCellRenderer%29),[setDefaultEditor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html#setDefaultEditor%28java.lang.Class,%20javax.swing.table.TableCellEditor%29))