# How to implement checkbox list java

Tags: java, swing, checkboxlist, jcheckbox

Probably a noob question, but im new to java. I have a need for a checkbox list which I found is not supported in swing, but I found this custom control here

http://www.devx.com/tips/Tip/5342

So I created a class file named CheckBoxList, and copied the code from the link into it:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class CheckBoxList extends JList
{
   protected static Border noFocusBorder =
                                 new EmptyBorder(1, 1, 1, 1);

   public CheckBoxList()
   {
      setCellRenderer(new CellRenderer());

      addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter()
         {
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e)
            {
               int index = locationToIndex(e.getPoint());

               if (index != -1) {
                  JCheckBox checkbox = (JCheckBox)
                              getModel().getElementAt(index);
                  checkbox.setSelected(
                                     !checkbox.isSelected());
                  repaint();
               }
            }
         }
      );

      setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
   }

   protected class CellRenderer implements ListCellRenderer
   {
      public Component getListCellRendererComponent(
                    JList list, Object value, int index,
                    boolean isSelected, boolean cellHasFocus)
      {
         JCheckBox checkbox = (JCheckBox) value;
         checkbox.setBackground(isSelected ?
                 getSelectionBackground() : getBackground());
         checkbox.setForeground(isSelected ?
                 getSelectionForeground() : getForeground());
         checkbox.setEnabled(isEnabled());
         checkbox.setFont(getFont());
         checkbox.setFocusPainted(false);
         checkbox.setBorderPainted(true);
         checkbox.setBorder(isSelected ?
          UIManager.getBorder(
           "List.focusCellHighlightBorder") : noFocusBorder);
         return checkbox;
      }
   }
}
```

The problem is I don't know how to implement it in my GUI file. I tried a lot of code, but they never showed an example. Just

> To use the class, simply instantiate it, then pass it an array of
>   JCheckBox objects (or subclasses of JCheckBox objects) by calling
>   setListData

So does that mean that I will not see the control in the Graphical Design view? My client wants to be able to edit it himself and add stuff so I want it to be easy and graphical if possible. If someone could show an example of instantiating it or give a good hint I would appreciate it. Thanks!

Comment: Use a one column `JTable` and an appropriate renderer and editor.

Comment: I would prefer not to

Comment: @trashgod Can you just tell me how?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I make a list with checkboxes in Java Swing?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19766/how-do-i-make-a-list-with-checkboxes-in-java-swing)

Answer (score 3):

> Can you just tell me how?

Use a one column `JTable` and an appropriate [renderer and editor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#editrender). Based on this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13919878/230513), the code below relies on the default renderer for a data value of type `Boolean.Class`. A more general example is cited [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6273093/230513).

[image]

```
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.TreeSet;
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.DefaultListModel;
import javax.swing.JCheckBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JList;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.event.TableModelEvent;
import javax.swing.event.TableModelListener;
import javax.swing.table.AbstractTableModel;
import javax.swing.table.TableCellRenderer;

/** @see https://stackoverflow.com/a/13919878/230513 */
public class CheckTable {

    private static final CheckModel model = new CheckModel(5000);
    private static final JTable table = new JTable(model) {

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredScrollableViewportSize() {
            return new Dimension(150, 300);
        }

        @Override
        public Component prepareRenderer(TableCellRenderer renderer, int row, int column) {
            JCheckBox jcb = (JCheckBox) super.prepareRenderer(renderer, row, column);
            jcb.setHorizontalTextPosition(JCheckBox.LEADING);
            jcb.setText(String.valueOf(row));
            return jcb;
        }
    };

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                JFrame f = new JFrame("CheckTable");
                f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                f.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 0));
                f.add(new JScrollPane(table));
                f.add(new DisplayPanel(model));
                f.pack();
                f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                f.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    private static class DisplayPanel extends JPanel {

        private DefaultListModel dlm = new DefaultListModel();
        private JList list = new JList(dlm);

        public DisplayPanel(final CheckModel model) {
            super(new GridLayout());
            this.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Checked"));
            this.add(new JScrollPane(list));
            model.addTableModelListener(new TableModelListener() {

                @Override
                public void tableChanged(TableModelEvent e) {
                    dlm.removeAllElements();
                    for (Integer integer : model.checked) {
                        dlm.addElement(integer);
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }

    private static class CheckModel extends AbstractTableModel {

        private final int rows;
        private List<Boolean> rowList;
        private Set<Integer> checked = new TreeSet<Integer>();

        public CheckModel(int rows) {
            this.rows = rows;
            rowList = new ArrayList<Boolean>(rows);
            for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
                rowList.add(Boolean.FALSE);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public int getRowCount() {
            return rows;
        }

        @Override
        public int getColumnCount() {
            return 1;
        }

        @Override
        public String getColumnName(int col) {
            return "Column " + col;
        }

        @Override
        public Object getValueAt(int row, int col) {
                return rowList.get(row);
        }

        @Override
        public void setValueAt(Object aValue, int row, int col) {
            boolean b = (Boolean) aValue;
            rowList.set(row, b);
            if (b) {
                checked.add(row);
            } else {
                checked.remove(row);
            }
            fireTableRowsUpdated(row, row);
        }

        @Override
        public Class<?> getColumnClass(int col) {
            return getValueAt(0, col).getClass();
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int col) {
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What did you wind up using?  Do you remember?

Comment: I try to go with the default renderer & editor, resorting to a custom implementation only when required.

Answer (score 2):

The code is expecting a list of JCheckBox objects - so this works

```
CheckBoxList cbList = new CheckBoxList();  // the class you have
JCheckBox check1 = new JCheckBox("One");
JCheckBox check2 = new JCheckBox("two");
JCheckBox[] myList = { check1, check2};    list of checkbox object
cbList.setListData(myList);   // set the list data for the object
```

Small Swing program using your class below

```
 util;

import javax.swing.*;

public class HelloWorldSwing {
private static void createAndShowGUI() {
    //Create and set up the window.
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("HelloWorldSwing");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    CheckBoxList cbList = new CheckBoxList();
    JCheckBox check1 = new JCheckBox("One");
    JCheckBox check2 = new JCheckBox("two");
    JCheckBox[] myList = { check1, check2};
    cbList.setListData(myList);
    frame.getContentPane().add(cbList);

    //Display the window.
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    //Schedule a job for the event-dispatching thread:
    //creating and showing this application's GUI.
    javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            createAndShowGUI();
        }
    });
}
```

}