# Is it possible to put JCheckBoxes in JTable cells, which do NOT contain booleans?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, checkbox, jtable

I know that a table cell in a JTable automatically gets a Checkbox if you set its class to Boolean.

However, I have a column in my JTable, which contains integer values. Is it possible to add Checkboxes to those (non-boolean) cells like in my poor drawing here:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/AfJ5x.png]

My goal is not to check those columns for true/false values, but rather to select the corresponding table rows and do something with them. I know that I could use multiple selection intervals in my ListSelectionModel instead, but I'd find it much more appealing with checkboxes.

Comment: Why cannot you create one more Boolean column and name it `selection` to keep the checkboxes logic?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. Aggregate the numeric and boolean attributes into a single `Value` and provide a suitable [renderer and editor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#editrender). Your implementation of `getColumnClass()` would then return `Value.class` for the relevant column. A complete example using `Double` is seen [here](https://sites.google.com/site/drjohnbmatthews/table), examined [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6273093/230513) and illustrated below. In outline,

```
class Value implements Comparable<Value> {

    private Boolean selected;
    private Integer value;

    public Value(Boolean selected, Double value) {
        this.selected = selected;
        this.value = value;
    }
    …
}

class ValueRenderer extends JCheckBox
    implements TableCellRenderer {

    @Override
    public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(
        JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected,
        boolean hasFocus, int row, int col) {
        Value v = (Value) value;
        this.setSelected(v.selected);
        this.setText(df.format(v.value));
        …
        return this;
    }
}

class ValueEditor extends AbstractCellEditor implements TableCellEditor, ItemListener {

    private ValueRenderer vr = new ValueRenderer();

    public ValueEditor() {
        vr.addItemListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public Object getCellEditorValue() {
        return vr.isSelected();
    }
    …
}
…
table.setDefaultRenderer(Value.class, new ValueRenderer());
table.setDefaultEditor(Value.class, new ValueEditor());
```

[image]

Comment: When I do that, I get a ClassCastException, because I cannot convert from String to Value... I tried changing the value inside the Value-class to String, but still I can't cast like this. So how could I achieve the same thing with Strings instead of Doubles or Integers ?

Comment: Verify that your `TableModel` actually contains instances of `Value` and has an implementation of `getColumnClass()` that returns `Value.class`.

Comment: Ah I Just forgot to Change my getValueAt method, now it works, thank you very much !

Comment: I can't select the checkboxes now though... which method do I have to alter, so that I can select the checkboxes and listen for changes in their true/false state ?

Comment: Check your implementation of `isCellEditable()`.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to override the `getColumnClass()` method in your table model.
[See JavaDoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/table/AbstractTableModel.html#getColumnClass(int)).

The other one is an own [TableCellEditor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/table/TableCellEditor.html) and / or [TableCellRenderer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/table/TableCellRenderer.html)

Answer (score -1):

Why not just create a new class which contains both a label and a checkbox and add that to your table?

```
import java.awt.*;

import javax.swing.*;

public class LabelWithCheckBox extends JPanel{

public LabelWithCheckBox(String text){
    setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
    JLabel jLabel = new JLabel(text);
    JCheckBox checkBox = new JCheckBox();

    add(jLabel, new GridBagConstraints(
            0, 0, 1, 1, 1.0, 1.0,
            GridBagConstraints.WEST, GridBagConstraints.NONE,
            new Insets(0, 0, 0, 0),
            0, 0
    ));

    add(checkBox, new GridBagConstraints(
            1, 0, 1, 1, 1.0, 1.0,
            GridBagConstraints.WEST, GridBagConstraints.NONE,
            new Insets(0, 0, 0, 0),
            0, 0
    ));
}

 public static void main(String args[]){
     JFrame frame = new JFrame();
     frame.add(new LabelWithCheckBox("Label text"));
     frame.setVisible(true);
     frame.setSize(100, 50);
 }
}
```

Comment: (1-) that is not how a JTable works. A JTable uses renderers to display the data.

Comment: @camickr Yes, maybe I should have made it clearer that you would add it through a renderer and not just assume that the OP would know how to.

Comment: A renderer won't help because it just paints the data. It is not a real component.  It doesn't allow you to "click" on the check box.

Comment: @camickr I see! Then I had misunderstood what it did exactly.